# Fix no module 'layer' in current Google Colab TF version

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I use Google colab (python3 GPU)

I want to run for example [this repo codes](https://github.com/tomlepaine/fast-wavenet) but I have an error when running demo ipynb in these lines:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from layers import (_causal_linear, _output_linear, conv1d, dilated_conv1d)
```

When I run these two lines I have an error "no module layer"

I don't think this is a bug or something, because this repo has over 1000 stars.
I think this is rather a tf version problem.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What version of TensorFlow does that library expect? Colab always uses the latest stable version of TensorFlow (currently 1.12), so it's possible that library needs an update to support the latest version of TensorFlow.

Answer (score 1):

"Layers" is a module in the package that you linked NOT in Tensorflow. See [here](https://github.com/tomlepaine/fast-wavenet/blob/master/wavenet/layers.py).

BTW if you wanted to import from a submodule of tensor flow you would have to do `from tensorflow.package import ...`.